# How to access the "findById" method of a RESTful service through "getJSON"?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is the following code of my RESTful service class:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/empresas")
public class EmpresaEndpoint {

    @Inject
    private EmpresaRB empresaRB;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response findById(@PathParam("id") final Long id) {
        //TODO: retrieve the empresas
        Empresa empresas = null;
        if (empresas == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        return Response.ok(empresas).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Empresa> listAll(
            @QueryParam("start") final Integer startPosition,
            @QueryParam("max") final Integer maxResult) {
        //TODO: retrieve the empresa
        return empresaRB.getEmpresas();
    }

}
```

If I wanted to access all the data stored on "Empresa" via jQuery, I would do:

```
$.getJSON( "rest/empresas", function( data ) {
  //whatever is needed.
}
```

The code above would access the "listAll" method. So how can I access the "findById" method and pass the necessary parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a variable called empresaId that holds the id for the entity, this should work.

```
$.getJSON( "rest/empresas/" + empresaId, function(data) { 
  // Whatever is required here    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well without having used that particular framework, it looks like it's mapping to the right method based on the path - it will use `findById` if the path has an ID, e.g.

```
$.getJSON("rest/empresas/100", function(data) {
  // ...
}
```

(That will find the item with ID 100... obviously substitute the ID of the item you want to find. We don't know where that's coming from, but `"rest/empresas/" + id` may well be all you need.)

Comment: This way I'm getting a 404. I already tried to add the Id, but with no success. Either trying to access the json data via browser (adding some Id to the url) and retrieving the result in runtime.

But thanks for your time!

Comment: @MarcusKaefer: Have you tried without the `empresas` in the URL? Perhaps the Path annotation *overrides* the class-level annotation? Or perhaps it's badly configured, and it should be `@Path("/empresas/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")`. Is this your server code, which can be changed if necessary?

Comment: The thing is that I can't access the data via browser by typing "/rest/empresas/XXX". When I type "/resources/empresas" I can visualize the JSON data like this:

{"cdEmpresa":2,"nmEmpresa":"2-MAXICON - DESENV"},{"cdEmpresa":3,"nmEmpresa":"3-MAXICON - DESENV"};
{"cdEmpresa":4,"nmEmpresa":"4-MAXICON - DESENV"}

Comment: @MarcusKaefer: That's why I've suggested changing the code on the server - it may be misconfigured. (It doesn't help that we don't know which web framework it's using.)

Comment: I'm using JPA with Hibernate and the server is JBoss

Answer (score 0):

In my initial code, there was no query being connected to the variable "empresa", on the method findById().

I created a query on the repository class and assigned it to the variable. Problem Solved.

Thank you all for the time lended.